# Kubernetes cordon node command

Tags: kubernetes

If I cordon a node, I make it unschedulable, so this command applies a taint on this node to mark it as NoSchedule with kubernetes specific key. But then when I create a taint with NoSchedule effect and add another key value, for ex. env=production and create a toleration on pod to match this key and effect NoSchedule - pod anyway won't be scheduled on this node. Why so?
Maybe cordon command somehow internally marks node as no schedule and not only applies a taint

P.S After running `kubectl uncordon <node>` the toleration worked

Comment: You answered your own question by applying the `kubectl uncordon <node>` command.  Since you previously had it cordoned, the scheduler won't schedule any pods to that node until you "uncordon" the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right as you have already applied the

**cordon** on the node

K8s won't schedule the PODs on it unless and until you mark the node with uncordon.

```
kubectl uncordon <node>
```